# Android: Draw Canvas on Webview

Tags: android

I am using a WebView to display an image that is in my resources, using a WebView because I need it to be zoomable. Dynamically I need to be able to draw points on the image, it is a map. To do this I am trying to put a canvas on top of the loaded image. The canvas would have the points drawn on it.

```
mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/map.png");

Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.drawARGB(10, 0, 100, 12);//This is just random. It is where I would draw the points
mWebView.draw(c);
```

The last 3 lines in the code do not appear to do anything.

Is there a better way to go about drawing on top of a WebView? Is it even possible this way?

Comment: Have you tried making a subclass of `WebView` and overriding the `onDraw()` method? The method receives a `Canvas` parameter, and you can use that to draw on the image.

Comment: There are plenty of third-party zoomable `ImageView` replacements, trivially found via your favorite search engine. Using a `WebView` is not required.

Comment: I have tried it in onDraw(), didnt work. 
@CommonsWare I tried to find one, but failed get a smooth solution. Can you find it for us?

Answer (score 0):

In you last line, you are giving it a new canvas (which will not have map.png loaded).

What you should do is:

- Create a new class which extends WebView
- override its onDraw() method, like:

  ```
  public class MyWebView extends WebView{

      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
          super.onDraw(canvas);
          canvas.drawPoint(yourPoint);
     }
  }
  ```

Make its variable:

```
        MyWebView mWebView = new MyWebView(this);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/map.png");
```

add this view to your Main View of your layout.

```
       myMainView.add(wv);
```

Done!