# Unable to handle events while drawing on a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

My reqm is to draw something on a HTML page in android. So i have a WebView in layout which is loading HTML url and  then adding another view which is drawing a canvas on my layout. The issue is to handle the events so that ontouch it will draw as well as scroll the HTML page. For me either scroll or draw works. Both are not working together.

```
rl.addView(myView); //To add View extended class on which to draw canvas on relativelayout
rl.addView(webview); //To add HTML page on relativelayout
```

both are not working together. Either one of the two works at a time. 
Please help me.

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900157/android-draw-canvas-on-webview) but didn't get solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please help on this as its a urgent requirement.